# Using Sed with Regular Expressions for Sub-string replacement

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, sed

I'm using Ubuntu Natty.

I'm trying to use sed to do a string replacement using the command line.

The part of the text file (app.config) I'm trying to replace is as below:

```
%% http is a list of IP addresses and TCP ports that the Riak
%% HTTP interface will bind.
{http, [ {"127.0.0.1", 8098 } ]},
```

And I'm trying to replace the IP address with something else. Here's my code:

```
 ip="192.168.10.12"    
 sed -i "s/\(\{http,[\t ]*\[[\t ]*\{\)\"[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\"/\1\"$ip\"/" /root/sandbox/app.config
```

However, I get an error `sed: -e expression #1, char 103: Invalid preceding regular expression`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add regex flag, edit your regular expression removing escapes from keywords like `(` or `{`. Seems working now

```
ip="192.168.10.12"
sed -i -r "s/(\{http,[\t ]*\[[\t ]*\{)\"[1-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\"/\1\"$ip\"/" /root/sandbox/app.config
```

Comment: I get `sed: -e expression #1, char 104: invalid reference \1 on \'s' command's RHS` using -r as above. msg is pointing to \1, but that seems appropriate. Bug in sed? Also, let's compare sed versions ;-), mine is `GNU sed version 4.2.1`. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter, I have the same one: `GNU sed version 4.2.1`

Comment: weifd ;-). Thanks for sharing. On to the next problem and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed  "s/\({http,[\t ]*\[[\t ]*{\)\"[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\"/\1\"$ip\"/"
```

You don't need to escape `{`'s when they are literal.